# Why does Sinatra not have a Homepage setting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am starting a new site in WordPress.
I did a fresh install and Activated the Sinatra theme.
Then I created a new Page I want to use as the home page and put a little place holder content in there.

Then I went to "Settings -> Reading" in the Dashboard.
And there is no "Your homepage displays" section with the "Your latest posts" and "A static page (select below)" options.

Is this a Sinatra thing?

I'm a total newbie in WordPress and I thought I finally found a really good flexable theme where I can get better control over the header.  But now this.  Totally confused as to why this is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You have to have at least one page published for that option to show up in "Settings -> Reading".  My page was still in draft mode.